# trouble combining image upload and sql query

Tags: php, sql

i am having an issue executing an SQL/SQLi query and uploading an image at the same time.
I am able to do one or the other but not sure how to combine the code.

The main code:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
 ?>
```

The above code works for image upload

```
<?php
$venuename=$_POST['venuename'];
$adress=$_POST['adress'];
$venuetype=$_POST['venuetype'];
$venuedesc=$_POST['description'];

if($venuename&&$adress&&$venuetype&&$venuedesc)
    {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_venues (venue_name,venue_description,venue_adress,venue_type) VALUES ('$venuename','$venuedesc','$adress','$venuetype')");
    header("Location: created_venue.php?");
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div id="venuevalidation">Please complete all fields!</div>';
    }
?>
```

The above works for inserting data however my attempts to combine the two are unsuccessful, any suggestions?
Apologies for the large post! Thanks

Comment: Please show your combined code and let us know what goes wrong.

Comment: The initial attempt was one after the other. The main issue is i don't know how to combine them.

Comment: All resolved! issues with bracketing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All resolved, the issue was with brackets! the code was executing on one part and not moving to the next.